# What is the address of a null pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, null

This is a quite basic question but I've been looking everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

Consider the following code:

```
myFunction(MyObject** obj) {...}

int main()
{
  MyObject *obj = NULL;
  myFunction(&obj);
}
```

What is the result of this?

Is `&obj` NULL? undefined? Does it segfault?

Comment: It's the same idea as taking the address of any other local variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `&obj` will not be NULL,
it will be the memory address holding the "value of obj", the pointer to MyObject.
It is as simple as

```
int x = 0;
int *ptrTox = &x;
```

In this case ptrTox will contain address of x, and not zero. It can be any valid address.

Answer (score 4):

A pointer is simply a variable that stores an address (with a constraint on the type of what lies at this address).

So while it stores an address, it also has its own address in memory.

In your case, `&obj` is the address of this variable, and is neither `NULL` nor undefined, and accessing it won't segfault (if you avoid performing operations with `obj` that need to access what's pointed at, obviously). Indeed, the variable `obj` is declared and defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your myFunction() is getting the address of the obj (as passing &obj). You have created a pointer of MyObject class named obj. So It should not be null. Which hold address of memory of obj pointer.

Segfault is described here
[What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/3049917)